# problemas con api rest php y front angular ($_POST)

Tags: php, angular, typescript

tengo un problema a la hora de hacer POST desde un front en angular a un api php, desde el front estoy trayendo datos con GET pegandole a esta misma api rest sin ningun problema pero cuando quiero mandar un post me trae null como resultado.

```
    const body = { route: 'prueba' };

    this.http.post<any>(api, body).subscribe({
        next: data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: error => {
            this.errorMessage = error.message;
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        }
```

y para probar desde php solo estoy haciendo esto:

```
if($_POST['route']=='prueba'){
    echo json_encode('pruebaaaaaa');
}
```

tambien intente sin el json_encode, en php no estoy usando ningun frame es poo puro y los headers que tengo para los cors son:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, REQUEST");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, REQUEST");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

otra prueba que hice es fuera de ese if hacer un echo a algo por ejemplo echo 'prueba' y si funciona pero cuando pongo $_POST no lo reconoce, la verdad es muy extraño jamas me habia pasado, es cierto que es mi primera app con angular no se si la configuracion de angular tendra algo que ver.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

Creo que te falto añadir Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
Espero que te sriva saludos.